# I'm confused about the arguments that i passe to a selector function that uses reselect inside containers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect, mapstatetoprops

I'm learning the usage of reselect, but i'm confused about the way i make use of the memoized selector in inside my container.

I've got a component called `Summary` that received 3 props thats are `subtotal, tipAmount , total` .

It looks like this `export const Summary = ({ subtotal = 0, tipAmount = 0, total = 0 })=>{...}`.And those props are being inject my the connect `HOC` inside a dedicated `container` that i've called `SummaryContainer` with the following code.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Summary } from '../components/Summary';
import {
  selectTipAmount,
  selectSubtotal,
  selectTotal
} from '../store/items/selectors';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const subtotal = selectSubtotal(state);

  const tipAmount = selectTipAmount(state);
  const total = selectTotal(state);

  return {
    subtotal,
    tipAmount,
    total
  };
};

export const SummaryContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Summary);
```

As you can see this code uses 3 selectors `selectTipAmount` , `selectSubtotal` and `selectTotal` that i'm importing from a selector file with the follwing code.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
const selectTipPercentage = (state) => state.tipPercentage;


export const selectSubtotal = createSelector([selectItems], (items) =>
  items.reduce((acc, { price, quantity }) => acc + price * quantity, 0)
);

export const selectTipAmount = createSelector(
  [selectSubtotal, selectTipPercentage],
  (subtotal, tipPercentage) => subtotal * (tipPercentage / 100)
);

export const selectTotal = createSelector(
  [selectSubtotal, selectTipAmount],
  (subtotal, tipAmount) => subtotal + tipAmount
);


export const selectItemWithTotal = createSelector([selectItems], (items) =>
  items.map((item) => ({ ...item, total: item.price * item.quantity }))
);


export const selectItem = (state, props) =>
  state.items.find((item) => item.uuid === props.uuid);

export const selectItemTotal = createSelector(
  [selectItem],
  (item) => item.price * item.quantity
);
```

So here is my problem :

When i call write `const total = selectTotal(state);`inside `mapStateToProps` i passe to the `total` constant the results of the execution of `selectTotal(state) selector` and when i look at the `argument`, it's `state`.It looks like i'm invoking the `selectTotal selector` by passing and `state` argument, but in the actuel implementation it isn't a function that takes a `state param`.In the actual implementation that selection equals the result of `createSelect function` like this:

```
export const selectTotal = createSelector(
  [selectSubtotal, selectTipAmount],
  (subtotal, tipAmount) => subtotal + tipAmount
);
```

I haven't seen where the state `argument` is being passed.What is going on?

The code works perfectly but i'm lost about where the `state` argument is being used.

When i look at `selectItems selector` it makes sens, but with selectors that are created with `createSelector` i'm lost.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easiest to think of `reselect` selectors as sort of the "opposite" of redux reducer functions. With reducer functions each reducer owns a chunk of state and when they are combined they form a reducer tree where once they are all combined form the *entire* `state` object.

The selectors are basically doing the opposite. They start with simple selectors that take the *entire* `state` object and pluck out chunks of it. These sub-state chunks can then be fed into created selectors to pluck out smaller chunks (*or compute derived state*). The inputs used in `createSelector` are a sort of "dependency", when one of them updates then the selector recomputes its value.

`createSelector` is essentially a higher order function that consumes "dependencies" and a result function, and returns a function that consumes the `state` object. When you call `selectSubtotal` and pass `state` you are really passing `state` to a selector tree (*or set of trees*).

For example, when `state.items` updates the `selectItems` selector that is an input to `selectSubtotal` will update its return value. This update will trigger `selectSubtotal` to then recompute its value, and so on for any other selectors that use `selectSubtotal` as an input.

If you are curious, the resultant selector function will also have a `resultFunc` property that matches the computing function originally passed to `createSelector`. For example, `selectTipAmount.resultFunc` will be `(subtotal, tipPercentage) => subtotal * (tipPercentage / 100)`, called like `selectTipAmount.result.Func(subTotal, tipPercentage);`. I use this heavily when unit testing my selectors since I really don't care about memoizing a value, but rather that they correctly compute derived state; I won't need to mock up an entire state object that matches the selector dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The `createSelector` function returns a function so in `const mySelectorFunction = createSelector...` the value `mySelectorFunciton` is a function.

A simple implementation of `createSelector` without memoization would be:

```js
const createSelector = (functions=[],calculatorFunction) => {
  // you could do memoize(calculatorFunction) to implement memoization
  //the function returned is the selectOnePlusTwo in demo below
  return (...args) =>
    // when this function is called then it will call functions with args
    //  and pass the returning values to calculatorFunction
    calculatorFunction(...functions.map(fn=>fn(...args)))
}
// demo createSelector
const state = { one:1,two:2 }
const selectOne = state=>state.one
const selectTwo =  state=>state.two
const selectOnePlusTwo = createSelector(
  [selectOne,selectTwo],
  (one,two)=>one+two
)
console.log(
  'one plus two:',
  selectOnePlusTwo(state)
)
```

Memoization is a nice touch that could make your code slightly more performant by skipping virtual DOM compare but what usually causes havoc on your performance is passing in a new handler reference that will cause this comparison to fail and make React re paint that DOM, for example `<SomeComponent onClick={()=>newRefCreated} />` will re paint whatever `SomeComponent` generates because the `onClick` changes every time. This is why there is a [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

I'd say that the power of `createSelector` comes from easily re usable code and preventing duplicate implementation. If in the example above `state.one` would change to a string I need to only refactor the `selectOne` function and all other selectors depending on `state.one` would still work.